# Invertible elements in a discrete valuation ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, inverse, valuation-theory, local-rings

I was starting to read 'Local Fields : Jean-Pierre Serre', and in the first section, it says that "the invertible elements of $A$ (a discrete valuation ring) are those elements that do not belong to $m(A)$ (here $m(A)$ is the unique non-zero prime ideal of $A$)".

I do not understand why it is being said that all elements outside $m(A)$ are invertible. Even if we are talking about the field of fractions, the whole $ A\setminus\{0\}$ should be the field of fractions because $A$ being a discrete valuation ring is an integral domain.

$\textbf{Definition}$ : A ring $A$ is called a discrete valuation ring if it is a principal ideal domain that has a unique non-zero prime ideal $m(A)$.

Comment: It may help to consider an example, for instance $A$ being the set of all rationals with odd denominator. Here the maximal ideal is generated by $2$.

Comment: The invertibility is *in the ring* not in its fraction field. For example, in the $p$-adic integers the invertible elements are those not in $p\mathbf Z_p$. Nonzero numbers in $p\mathbf Z_p$ are *not invertible in* $\mathbf Z_p$. I assume you already know what $p$-adic numbers are. If not then you should not be reading Serre's book but find something more basic (Gouvea's or Koblitz's books, for instance). In $\mathbf Z$, the invertible elements (its units) are $\pm 1$, not all nonzero integers.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown is $A$ even a PID?

Comment: @user1430 Yes${}$.

Comment: I think I got the answer : If $a$ is any element of $m(A)$, then obviously it is not invertible because otherwise $m(A) = A$. If $a$ is outside $m(A)$, then consider $(a)$, the ideal generated by $a$, but if $a$ is not a unit, then it is contained in some maximal ideal, only maximal ideal in this ring is $m(A)$ , implies $a$ is in $m(A)$, contradiction.

Comment: @user1430: Yes, that's exactly it.

Answer (score 2):

For sake of contradiction, assume there is $a\in A/m(A)$ which is not invertible. Then there exists a maximal ideal $I$ of $A$ which contains $a$. Since $A$ is local, $I=m(A)$. Thus $a\in m(A)$, which is absurd.

Answer (score 1):

The property of $A$ being a local ring is enough. Let $M$ be its unique maximal ideal. We show that $A^\times = A \setminus M$.

Let $a\in A$ and $(a)$ the principal ideal generated by $a$.
We use the easy fact that $a\in A^\times \iff (a) = A$.

- If $a\in M$, then $(a) \subseteq M \neq A$ and hence $a\notin A^\times$.
- If $a\notin M$, then $(a) \nsubseteq M$. Now by the maximality of $M$ we have $(a) = A$ and thus $a\in A^\times$.